# Visual Paradigm for UML Using Conditional Nodes

Tags: uml, conditional-statements, activity-diagram, visual-paradigm

I am attempting to use Visual Paradigm to produce an activity diagram. I want to use a conditional node. I have placed ond in my diagram, named it and now see there are two areas Test and Body. I want to enter a test condition but see no way to do that. The area marked test does not seem editable, what gives?
I've searched the web and S/Ofor this answer even visual paradigms own forms and guides, but as yet have come across no explanation of how this feature works. I just want to enter a condition such as X == true.

Comment: What are "ond", S/Ofor, "what gives"? And put here the diagram, please.

Comment: @Gangus S/O stack over flow and I left out a space. No diagram needed really because the question is aimed at those who use Visual Paradigm and know how to utilize the conditional node feature.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check if X (X=true is the same as simply X), or if a>b, there is Decision node for it. It looks as a rhombus with arrows to and from it.

Conditional node is something that works only on some condition. It is not the branching, you can put there components, that simply don't exist without that condition.

Comment: I know how to use a rhombus represent a decision, the question was specifically in relation to the use of the Structured Conditional Node feature which uses the alternate syntax (a segmented rounded box). In UML there are various ways to represent this rounded blocks, and different CASE tools all have their on take on what is expected and valid syntax.  Thanks for answering though. Turns out one cannot free type a condition like For Each Record in List or X < 10, rather one has to overcomplicate things by drawing a Branch node (rhombus) and path into of flow into the body.